# On the norm of operator: Is it a closed set?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

**Theorem.** Suppose $\mu(X)<\infty$, $f\in L^1(\mu)$, $S$ is a closed set in the complex plane, and the averages $$A_E(f)=\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_E f\;d\mu$$ lie in $S$ for every $E\in\mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(E)> 0$. Then $f(x)\in S$ for almost all $x\in X$.

**Ingredients**: $\mu$ a finite positive measure on $\mathcal{A}$ and $g\in L^1(\mu)$. Let $\Phi$ a linear bounded operator in $L^1(\mu)$. We have for all $E\in\mathcal{A}$ that $$\left | \int_E g\; d\mu\right|\le \lVert \Phi \rVert\cdot \lVert \chi_E \rVert_1 =\lVert \Phi \rVert\cdot \mu(E),$$ therefore $$\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\left | \int_E g\;d\mu \right |\le \lVert \Phi \rVert.$$

> Why the above theorem implies that $$\left | g(x) \right |\le \lvert \Phi \rVert\quad\text{a.e.}$$
> The norm of operator $\Phi$ is a closed set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closed ball in the complex plane of radius $\|\Phi\|$ is a closed set.